# Can someone help me with this algorithm to light up 3 LEDs?

Tags: python, algorithm, raspberry-pi

So I just got a Raspberry Pi and I've been playing around with some basic algorithms and setups.

I made a circuit with a button and 3 LEDs. When the button is pressed I want the first LED to light up, if the button is held down for 2 seconds, the second LED lights up, if the button is held down for 2 more seconds, the third LED lights up. Then when the button is released all three LEDs go out. Right now only the first LED is lighting up.

Could someone look over my code and help me figure out why it's not working?

I don't think there's a problem with the physical wiring on the breadboard but if we can't find anything wrong with the code I'll look for problems there too.

Here's my Python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(11, False)
GPIO.output(13, False)
GPIO.output(15, False)

def seconds_passed(oldepoch):
    if time.time() - oldepoch >= 2:
        return True

while True:
    input_value = GPIO.input(12)
    if input_value == False:
        print "The button has been pressed, lighting first LED."
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        while input_value == False:
            input_value = GPIO.input(12)
        if input_value == False and seconds_passed() == True:
            print "The button is still being pressed, lighting second LED."
            GPIO.output(13, True)
            while input_value == False:
                input_value = GPIO.input(13)
            if input_value == False and seconds_passed() == True:
                print "The button is still being pressed, lighting third LED."
                GPIO.output(15, True)
                while input_value == False:
                    input_value = GPIO.input(15)
        print "The button has been released, extinguishing LEDs."
    if input_value == True:
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        GPIO.output(13, False)
        GPIO.output(15, False)
```

Please and thank you!

Comment: I notice that you call the seconds_passed function without any arguments in your while loop...  and oldepoch doesn't default to anything...

Answer (score 2):

You have an endless loop

```
while True:
    input_value = GPIO.input(12)
    if input_value == False:
        print "The button has been pressed, lighting first LED."
        GPIO.output(11, True)

*** here ***
*** while input_value == False:
            input_value = GPIO.input(12)
```

You need to get out of this while loop to light LEDs 2 and 3, but you never get out of the while loop until you release the button

```
        if input_value == False ...
```

You then get to this test when you release the button, but this test needs the button pressed before it can try to light LEDs 2 and 3. Because the button had to be released to get here, this never matches. All the code below that 'if' doesn't run.

And you've got the same problem again and again with LEDs 2 and 3 having their own foreverloops, if the code ever got that far.

You need a different design. Like this (untested) pseudocode:

```
import time

button_now_pressed = False

while True:
    # Update button state each time through the loop

    button_was_pressed = button_now_pressed
    button_now_pressed = not GPIO.input(12)


    # Process button state, compared to
    # previous run through the loop    

    if (not button_was_pressed) and button_now_pressed:
        # button was pressed since last loop run

        # save time button was pressed
        press_time = time.time()

        # Light LED 1


    if button_was_pressed and (not button_now_pressed):
        # button was released since last loop run
        # turn LEDs off


     if button_was_pressed and button_now_pressed:
        # button stayed down

        # how long has it been pressed? 
        current_time = time.time()
        if current_time - press_time > 2:
            # light LED 2
        if current_time - press_time > 4:
            # light LED 3
```

(I'm assuming from your code that GPIO.input() normally returns True, and goes False when the button is pressed. I don't actually know if that's correct).